# Recovering files on drive that was previously dualbooting Windows and linux. Now I only run linux

Tags: linux, windows, file-recovery

I lost some files that are really important and was located on my linux system, when I was dual-booting linux and windows 10. Completely forgot about them when I formatted the drive and installed only Windows 10. Is there a way to try and recover the files?

Comment: Recover them from your back-up; if they weren't backed up, then they weren't really important, by definition. That said, if you did a quick format, then the file data may still be on the disc and possibly recoverable. There are lots of data recovery software packages, according to the OS you are using, which is unclear - your title and your question say the opposite of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by the files not being important by definition, since they weren't backed up? The files I am talking about are not system files but personal files. I am not sure how you think I contradict myself; before the format I was running both Linux and Windows on my machine, and after format (now) I run only Windows.
The recovery software I seem to be able to find only find old windows files..

Comment: A disc can fail at any time, so you need to be prepared for this to happen by backing up files you can't afford to lose. It follows therefore that any file not backed up is one that you can recover or manage without. Your message title says "Now I only run linux", while your question says you "installed only Windows 10". I don't think I can be blamed for being confused. If you are running Windows, maybe you should try running a Linux Live Boot disc and see if utilities like `testdisk` or `extundelete` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you did the format the files are deleted for good however you can try something like EaseUS or bartpe to recover files depending on how long it's been, they may be lost forever.